# Syntax Error in cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

I wrote a program in python and while converting to exe file I am getting a Syntax Error.

My Code:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('Cake Rush.py')]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name='Cake Rush',
    options={'build_exe':{"packages":['pygame'], 'include_files':['cake.bmp','doctor.bmp','door.bmp','pill.bmp','player.bmp','wall.bmp','web.bmp']}},
    description = 'Cake Rush Game',
    executables = executables
    )
```

Error:

```
options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"],"include_files":["cake.bmp", "doctor.bmp", "door.bmp", "pill.bmp", "player.bmp", "wall.bmp", "web.bmp"]}},

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: showing your code would be a nice addition

Comment: the line you're pointing to is valid syntax. Full Traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are missing a closing curly bracket after `packages`.

Try the following line:

`options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"]},"include_files":{["cake.bmp", "doctor.bmp", "door.bmp", "pill.bmp", "player.bmp", "wall.bmp", "web.bmp"]}},`